# How to send the bunch of messages at a time to Azure Storage Queue using Azure Logic App?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-storage-queues

[image]

- **Action 1**: Recurrence Trigger for every 5 Seconds.
- **Action 2**: Sending Multiple Messages at a time

Above design send one message for every 5 seconds but not the multiple messages to the specified Storage Queue.

Message Content: Hello SA Queue, This is message with Guid() function.

Unable to find the connector/configuration for sending bulk of messages at a time.
Could anyone assist me here.

Comment: Of course it's only going to send one message every five seconds, your recurrence trigger runs every 5 seconds and you send one message each time.  What would the multiple messages contain?  Sorry mate but we need a lot more information to be able to help.  What is the outcome you are trying to achieve? ... and please don't say, "multiple messages to a storage queue", that part is obvious.

Comment: Sure @Skin, It's a PoC. Multiple messages contains the common message with some Guid Id and from the batch messages received from logic app, each message will be processed one by one with some code in the C# Console Application (business logic) according to requirement.

Comment: Ok, so you just want to drop a whole heap of messages on a queue for testing and you want to do that every 5 seconds? Have you looked at using a loop?

Comment: Correct Understanding @Skin but didn't know about how to use a loop technique. Could you please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this by using an `Until` action ...

[image: Flow]

As you can see, it's going to loop 20 times (you can change that) and drop 20 messages on the same queue.